# Accessing the Properties of an object already in Scene in Unreal Engine using C++

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I am trying to learn more about raycasting in C++ and am trying to implement raycasts in a mini third-person game I am creating. In order to shoot a raycast, I first need to determine its starting location, which in this case I intend it to be from the center of the third-person camera already built-in.

In order to do that, however, I need to access the properties of the camera already in the scene and store its location in a variable using c++. I am relatively new to unreal so I have no idea how to access an object's properties that's already in the scene using C++.

Any help is appreciated

I am still searching, but I couldn't find a satisfying answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the camera itself is fairly easy:

```
APlayerCameraManager *camManager = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->PlayerCameraManager;

FVector camLocation = camManager->GetCameraLocation();
FVector camForward  = camManager->GetCameraRotation().Vector();
```

however getting the center of the view is better done via the HUD api and it's project/deproject functions.
It can also be accessed from the player controller with following API:

[Documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/APlayerController/DeprojectScreenPositionToWorld/index.html)

```
//Prototype
bool DeprojectScreenPositionToWorld
(
    float ScreenX,
    float ScreenY,
    FVector & WorldLocation,
    FVector & WorldDirection
) const
```

To get all objects of specific class that are already in scene you could use `TActorIterator`for example like follows:

```
//This will iterate over every static mesh that is placed in the world(scene).
for (TActorIterator<AStaticMeshActor> ActorItr(GetWorld()); ActorItr; ++ActorItr)
{
    // Same as with the Object Iterator, access the subclass instance with the * or -> operators.
    AStaticMeshActor *Mesh = *ActorItr;
    ClientMessage(ActorItr->GetName());
    ClientMessage(ActorItr->GetActorLocation().ToString());
}
```